# Ruby subtracting one microsecond when converting to string

Tags: ruby

I have a string timestamp:

```
ts = '1550989255.000300'
```

How can I parse `ts` in a `Time` or `Datetime` object as `t`, and have `t.strftime('%6N')` print correctly?

I did:

```
t = Time.at(ts.to_f)
t.strftime '%6N' #=> "000299"
```

Ruby chops off one microsecond when converting a timestamp to a string.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but might this be caused by the inaccuracies of floats? In any case, what is your question? So far, you’ve only described the issue, but not asked an actual question.

Comment: @jdno I just updated my question. It is a Ruby issue, not an ActiveRecord issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Yossi I think you're right. Looking at that now

Comment: Note: `ts = 1.003; t  = Time.at(ts); t.strftime '%6N'
 #=> "002999"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing floating point math inaccuracy. If you need higher precision, you should use [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).

```
require 'bigdecimal'

ts = BigDecimal('1550989255.000300')
t  = Time.at(ts)
t.strftime '%6N'

=> "000300"
```

Answer (score 2):

Rationals are more exact than Floats, and they are used more and more in Ruby.

```
ts = '1550989255.000300'
t  = Time.at(ts.to_r)  # to_r: a rational
p t.strftime '%6N'     # => "000300"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
ts = "1550989255.000300"
arr = ts.split('.')
t = Time.at(arr[0].to_i, arr[1].to_i)
t.strftime '%6N'
```

Comment: I am removing it – I think him and I typed it at the same time, I hadn't seen his when I typed mine.

Comment: We did type it simultaniously

Comment: I prefer this to using `BigDecimal` for three reasons: it employs the appropriate version of `Time::at` directly (no trickery), avoids the need to load the `BigDecimal` libary and the use of a `BigDecimal` object as the argument of `Time::at` is undocumented.

Comment: To reduce repetition and avoid the creation of  the variable `arr` you may wish to write `Time.at(*ts.split('.').map(&:to_i)) #=> 2019-02-24 06:20:55 +0000`.